# Авторизация на сайте через ВКонтакте. Что хранить в куках?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Для регистрации на сайте планирую использовать авторизацию через ВКонтакте при помощи authorization code flow. Это нужно, чтобы получить имя, фамилию, адрес почты.

Но мне нужно, чтобы через неделю пользователь зашел на сайт, и уже был авторизован.

Что хранить в куках для безопасного использования сайта и невозможности подмены аккаунта?

Как грамотно организовать структуру БД MySQL для хранения сессий?

Comment: Как правило для таких задач используют некий хеш токен. Т.е. после успешной авторизации в БД для каждого пользователя сохраняешь значение этого токена и в дальнейшем для аутентификации используешь его.

Comment: Безопасно ли хранить токены в БД?

Comment: Куда безопасней чем хранить его в куках ;)